# Install command line tool sqlite3

Tags: adb, sqlite, sqlite3

Trying to install `sqlite3` command line tool with :

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

But I still can't run ./sqlite3 - `nu souch file`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Try running sqlite without the "./"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run run sqlite3 open the terminal and type `sqlite3`

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Comment: Haha I was writing my comment right when you posted this.